# How do I print out the first upper case letter in a string or array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```js
function findUpper(text) {
    let arr = [];

    if (text.length === 0) {
        return arr;
    }

    if (text.charAt(0) === text[0].toUpperCase()) {
        arr.push(text[0]);
    }

    arr = arr.concat(findUpper(text.slice(1)));
    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
}

findUpper("i am a Web developer Student");
```

The desired output is "W", since it is the first upper case letter, But I cannot figure out how to print out that result.

Comment: Is the goal of your question to do this recursively, or are you happy with any approach?

Comment: any approach will do. I tried everything I could think of, but still no luck.

Comment: `function findUpper(text){let index = text.search(/[A-Z]/);return text.substring(index,index+1);}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid whitespace,since whitespace uppercase is equal to itself,also there is no need to use recursive function,just a iteration can do it

```js
function findUpper(text){
    let arr = [];
    
    if(text.length === 0){
        return arr;
    }
    for(let i=0;i<text.length;i++){
       let txt = text.charAt(i)
       // using txt.trim().length > 0 to remove whitespace
       if(txt.trim().length > 0 && txt === text[i].toUpperCase()){
        arr.push(txt);
       }
    }
    return arr;
}
   



console.log(findUpper("i am a Web developer Student")[0]);
```

---

Update: another way is to using `split()` first and then using iteration to find it

```js
function findUpper(text){
    let arr = [];
    
    if(text.length === 0){
        return arr;
    }
    text = text.split(" ").join("")
    for(let i=0;i<text.length;i++){
       let txt = text.charAt(i)
       if(txt === text[i].toUpperCase()){
        arr.push(txt);
       }
    }
    return arr;
}
   
console.log(findUpper("i am a Web developer Student")[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful. I was trying to solve this for more than a week now. Again, Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

From the sentence you need to take out the words first and then check the uppercase for the first letter of the word, which can be done as

```
function findUpper(text) {
let arr = text.split(" ")

var upperCaseWord = ""
if (arr.length == 0) {
return upperCaseWord;
}   
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
let word = arr[i];
let firstLetter = word.charAt(0)
if(firstLetter == firstLetter.toUpperCase()) {
upperCaseWord = word;
break;
}
}
return upperCaseWord;
}
console.log(findUpper("i am a Web developer Student"));
```